# multithreading: starting a thread to execute a query while another process keeps going

Tags: c#

I have a method that looks like this:

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
    foreach (SomeModel x in TheListOfSomeModel)
    {
        do some work
        ....
        if (SomeCondition)
        {
             x.ExecuteQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, `SomeModel` has a method that runs an update query that stores a property of the object into a field in the database. As the code is currently written, if the query needs to run, the whole loop is on hold until the query is done. If if can be of any use, there are only 5 elements in `TheListOfSomeModel`.

Apart from using `Parrallel ForEach`, how can I change this so that the `x.ExecuteQuery()` runs on a separate thread?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you want to use Parallel.ForEach?

Comment: @MikeParkhill: most of the time, SomeCondition will be false 90% of the time. Parrallel.ForEach adds some overhead and since the loop only runs 5 times, I think it'll be slower than a traditional foreach. I only want the threading to occur if the query actually runs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run it as a task like this...

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => x.ExecuteQuery());
```

Answer (score 2):

Be careful not to close over the loop variable when spawning a task / thread (unless you work with C# 5), also make sure you use a separate connection/context for each thread.

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
    foreach (SomeModel x in TheListOfSomeModel)
    {
        var model = x;
        //do some work
        ....
        if (SomeCondition)
        {
             Task.Factory.StartNew(() => model.ExecuteQuery());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Exception handling left out for brevity:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;    
....

public void SomeMethod()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>
    {
        foreach (SomeModel x in TheListOfSomeModel)
        {
            //do some work
            ....
            if (SomeCondition)
            {
                 x.ExecuteQuery();
            }
         }
     });
}
```

That will run it in a new thread. If are doing this with a UI and you get CrossThreadExceptions then you'll need to access UI controls via `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke`.